# Empty POST string inserting as zero in MySQL even though column is set to NULL

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem where my database column is set to NULL

```
`max_vol` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NULL,
```

and my $_POST['max_vol[]'] is an empty string ('') right up to the point of inserting or updating the row in the database (tested output with print_r()). It then inserts 0 (zero) instead of NULL.

If I explicitly set max_vol to NULL it then works.

```
$value['max_vol'] = empty($value['max_vol']) ? NULL : $value['max_vol'];
```

but why does this happen? I thought setting an empty string to MySQL (with NULL set) inserted NULL. Here is my original code. Is this something CodeIgniter's query builder changes?

```
$position_form_data = array(); // positions form data store

// process the form data into arrays for database operations
foreach( $_POST as $post_key=>$post_value ) {
    // ignore non-array post variables
    if( is_array( $post_value ) ) {
        foreach( $post_value as $form_key=>$form_value ) {
            if (!isset($position_form_data[$form_key])) {
                $position_form_data[$form_key] = array();
            }
            $position_form_data[$form_key][$post_key] = $form_value;
        }
    }
}
// if id exists db->update else db->insert
foreach($position_form_data as $value){

  // $value['max_vol'] = empty($value['max_vol']) ? NULL : $value['max_vol'];

  //  data for insert and replace db operations
  $data = array(
    'id' => $value['id'],
    'day' => $_POST['day'],
    'title' => $value['title'],
    'description' => $value['description'],
    'max_vol' => $value['max_vol'],
    'is_draft' => $is_draft,
    'project_id' => $_POST['project_id']
  );

  //print_r($data);exit();
  if( empty($value['id']) ) {
    $this->db->insert('positions', $data);
  } else {
    $this->db->replace('positions', $data);
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Empty POST String != NULL.its `''` and mysql will insert proper value(0 for integer type datas) if value is not proper.(here `''`)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any mistake, I can only recommend you try this:

```
if( ! isset($value['max_vol'])){
    if( is_null($value['max_vol'])){
        $_max_vol = NULL;
    }
    else{
        $_max_vol = NULL
    }
}
else{
    $_max_vol     = $value['max_vol'];
}

$data = array(
    'id' => $value['id'],
    'day' => $_POST['day'],
    'title' => $value['title'],
    'description' => $value['description'],
    'max_vol' => $_max_vol,
    'is_draft' => $is_draft,
    'project_id' => $_POST['project_id']
  );
```